# Configuring CDH cluster with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, anaconda, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

We are using CDH 5.8.3 community version and we want to add support for Python 3.5+ to our cluster

I know that Cloudera and Anaconda has such parcel to support Python, but this parcel support Python version 2.7.

What is the recommended way to enable Python version 3+ on CDH cluster?

Comment: OP - were you able to find an answer to this question?